# MongoDB document alias strategy

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, backwards-compatibility

Let's say we **already** have two documents :

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "537e1562bb20c702d8e66c7b" },
  "name": "Bob",
  "color": "Red"
}
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "537dc2cbbb20c71aa6610145" },
  "name": "Bob",
  "color": "Red"
}
```

So Bob has a duplicate but we have two ids. We want 1 "Bob" to be returned when we query red color but we also want simple **backwards compatibility** and keep those two ids.

So when we query either `537e1562bb20c702d8e66c7b` or `537dc2cbbb20c71aa6610145` to get Bob.

An awesomely simple way to do it (if `can't use an array for _id`) would have been:

```
{
  "_id": [
      { "$oid": "537e1562bb20c702d8e66c7b" },
      { "$oid": "537dc2cbbb20c71aa6610145" }
  ],
  "name": "Bob",
  "color": "Red"
}
```

What can be the simplest way to solve this problem in MongoDB?

Indexes is a solution with Bob but in a more complex database where we deal with slightly different (1-2 characters difference) posts, comments, titles, etc we will still not be able to retain unique documents with indexes.

Comment: I believe this will have to be handled in your application layer. I would say that you should create a cleanup process that goes back and looks for duplicates based on your rules. Add a new key "possible_duplicate", with an array of related oids.

Comment: ...and whenever I want to query _id field add an $or to check the "possible_duplicate" fields? Sounds good.

Comment: I would think so. The big issue is determining what an acceptable delay is for populating that possible duplicate, and placing that process appropriately. You may want to place that check in the method that creates your record (unless you are going to stop those duplicates going forward)

Comment: The real issue here is "what defines a duplicate?". Sure you have simple example here, but that is most definitely not the real world use case that you actually want answered. At any rate, the fact that you have "duplicate" entries is **your fault**, and **you** need to do something that avoids that. Or are you actually looking for a way to "find duplicates", based on certain criteria? We're not sure what you are asking. An "awesomely simlpe way" of finding "Bob" as just currently present this is to just search for "Bob", and get either of the two documents that are stored.

Comment: Relax Neil, I know **I** have to do something about it. Now, duplicate is a document with a Levenshtein distance 2 in `title` text field and same `age` and `color` field. At first there is doc no1 with title "Bob" and no2 with title "Mary". Then No2 gets its title updated to "Bo" and we define them "duplicates". So when I query their favorite color e.g. "red" we want "Sarah", "Jim" and either "Bob" or "Bo" because they are "duplicates" (and I care about their other fields which are going to be same in case: `age`). But also keep both _ids "alive".

Comment: Rather than being snarky you could have just clarified your question as you were actually asked. It is a lot easier for people to understand your problem if you clearly define your question rather than keep adding additional information as comments. So if you can clearly define what you call a duplicate then you might get some help on how to find them and mark them. Simply look at your question it is very unclear what exactly you want to do. Having an aditional field for possibles seems the logical choice. Once you know how to set them that is.